# Explain why OLED power supply fails

Tags: power-supply

Here is my simplified **schematic** :

[image: My Schematic]

The whole circuit gets its power from the PC's USB port (the circuit draws less than 50mA) via the FTDI.

This allows to create 5V rail.

The 5V rail generates a 3.3V rail thanks to the LM1117.

The 3.3V feeds the microcontroller (ESP82266 SoC).

I have logic level shifter so that the microcontroller (3V VCC) can be programmed through the PC (5V USB), plus some other irrelevant external modules.

I have an i2c multiplexer because I plan to connect modules that could share the same i2c addresses.

The important is the OLED screen (SSD1306).

Here is my **problem**:

If I power this circuit via the USB, the OLED screen is speckled/glitchy.

If I power this circuit through my bench power supply and inject +5V to my 5V rail, it also is glitchy.

If I inject +3.5V (value is not that important, i can be from 3 to 5V) to my 3V rail, the OLED screen shows perfectly fine animations.

**Questions**:

Why is that?

What do I need to do to solve this?

How come the 3V injection is able to reach my OLED screen (which is rated 3-5V vcc)?

**Addendum**:
The 3V rail has a 35V 1000 uF electrolytic capacitor, while the 5V rail has a 50V 220 uF one.

Comment: What decoupling do you have? Please add a detailed schematic.

Comment: Simplified schematics won’t cut it here. The details that make it not work aren’t shown. Show the actual schematic of the 3.3V regulator with all components you connected to its input and output – other than the loads themselves.

Comment: Also note that the maximum capacitance you can connect to USB VBUS directly is 10uF. If you need more than that to make the regulator stable, you need an inrush current limiter as well.

Comment: My primary suspects are the same as always: lack of decoupling and/or ground loop.

Comment: I'm afraid in addition this all is connected in a way which is quite far from a properly designed and built  PCB with generous ground area. Breadboard & loooong wires?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The 3V rail has a 35V 1000 uF electrolytic capacitor, while the 5V rail has a 50V 220 uF cap. I picked both randomly. I also have an external eeprom connected to the 5V rail (and to the shifter then multiplexer to the uController).

Comment: @user287001 wire are about 10cm long, all soldered to a prototyping board (not a breadboard with dupont wires)

Comment: Insert a photo  to evaporate wrong assumptions. BTW 10cm is a long wire for short rise time  pulses. Electrolytic capacitors without parallel ceramic ones are not enough. Often every logic IC has its own capacitor connected straight between its DC supply pins with max few mm wires.

Comment: The electrolytic capacitors are basically useless for decoupling, you need ceramics and they need to be placed correctly. Either post a picture of your circuit and ask how to do it or look up one of the many other questions here on decoupling.

Comment: @Musa Please address comments for clarification by fixing the question – editing it to add requested information. Then flag the comments as “no longer needed”. It’s rare that question comments should be “replied to” other than editing the question. If the question were great, such comments wouldn’t arise :)

Comment: @Musa This question lacks detail and should be closed unless you do the work in accurately documenting exactly what you did, so that we can see physical dimensions, layout, etc. I’m flagging for closure since we’ll be going in circles and the question is unanswerable and not useful to anyone, yourself included, as it stands.

Comment: Basically, until shown otherwise, the best we can presume is “you probably did everything wrong that was possible to get wrong”, and a comprehensive answer would need to go as far as showing a completed assembled circuit. Anything less would be of little help to you, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific power-up sequence that needs to be followed, make sure you follow it. You may also want to reset the module after power up. Make sure the power transitions from low to high with little noise and a clean ramp.

[image]
Source: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf